# How do I use ADF copy activity with multiple rows in source?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have source which is JSON array, sink is SQL server. When I use column mapping and see the code I can see mapping is done to first element of array so each run produces single record despite the fact that source has multiple records. How do I use copy activity to import ALL the rows?

```
 "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "schemaMapping": {
                            "['@odata.context']": "BuyerFinancing",
                            "['@odata.nextLink']": "PropertyCondition",
                            "value[0].AssociationFee": "AssociationFee",
                            "value[0].AssociationFeeFrequency": "AssociationFeeFrequency",
                            "value[0].AssociationName": "AssociationName",
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ADF support cross apply for json array. Please check the example in this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#jsonformat-example

For schema mapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#schema-mapping

Comment: I'm a little confused where this format goes into. Does it go into my pipeline source?

Comment: Your source dataset. You could use ADF UI to help you generate the pipeline. in dataset, connection tab, you choose json format, then there is a button for you to parse json.

Comment: My source is `Rest resource`, I don't option to choose `json` as format there.

Comment: For rest source, there is also a collectionReference definition under mapping tab. You could use that. Please reference this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#schema-mapping

Comment: @FangLiu is it possible to get the data from a array which look likes {UserIds:["1","2","3"]}?. I want the output to become each Id will go on individual row

Comment: Have you checked about link? I think cross apply is what you want, right?

Comment: I dont see any cross apply in ADF v2. Please tell me where I can find this..

Answer (score 1):

Use * as the source field to indicate all elements in json format.  For example, with json:

```
{
"results": [
     {"field1": "valuea", "field2": "valueb"},
     {"field1": "valuex", "field2": "valuey"}
    ]
}
```

and a database table with a column result to store the json.  The mapping with results as the collection and * and the sub element will create two records with:

```
{"field1": "valuea", "field2": "valueb"}
{"field1": "valuex", "field2": "valuey"}
```

in the result field.

[Copy Data Field Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbSo7.png)